# Differential Equation $y'''-3y''=x^2-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'''-3y''=x^2-1$
I'm not sure how to solve this. I tried to use the method of undetermined coefficients but the third derivative of $(x^2)-1$ is $0$. Can that be correct?

Comment: Use $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+d$ instead of $Ax^2+Bx+C$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y''=v$ then try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As Saheb alluded to in his answer, that differential equation is nothing more than a first-order equation in $y''$, so you can treat $y''$ as a regular function, solve for it, and the find the second antiderivative of the answer you get by doing that; that will be $y$.

Comment: so youre saying to treat this equation as y"-3y'=(x^2)-1?

Comment: More like $y'-3y=x^2-1$, or rather, $v'-3v=x^2-1$, where $v=y''$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'''-3y''=x^2-1 \implies R^3-3R^2=R^2(R-3)=0 \implies R=0,3$$
$$y_H=c_1e^{3x}+c_2+c_3x$$
For the particular solution you need a polynomial of degree at least 4

$$y_P=Bx^4+Cx^3+Dx^2$$

---

Or just integrate directly
$$y'''-3y''=x^2-1 $$
$$y''-3y'=\frac {x^3}3-x+K_1 $$
Integrate again
$$y'-3y=\frac {x^4} {12}-\frac {x^2}2+K_1x+K_2 $$
Simple first ode now...

---

Or consider it as first order if you substitute $y''=z$

$$y'''-3y''=x^2-1$$
$$z'-3z=x^2-1$$
$e^{-3x}$ as integrating factor
$$(ze^{-3x})'=(x^2-1)e^{-3x}$$
Integrate
$$ze^{-3x}=\int(x^2-1)e^{-3x}dx=\frac{e^{-3x}}3+\int x^2e^{-3x}dx$$
$$y''=\frac 13+e^{3x}\int x^2e^{-3x}dx$$
$$y''=\frac 13-\frac {x^2}{3}+\frac {2e^{3x}}3\int xe^{-3x}dx$$
$$y''=-\frac {x^2}{3}-\frac {2x}9+\frac 7{27}+K_1e^{3x}$$
Integrate twice to get the final solution
$$y'=-\frac {x^3}{9}-\frac {x^2}{9}+\frac {7x}{27}++K_1e^{3x}+K_2$$
$$\boxed{y=-\frac {x^4}{36}-\frac {x^3}{27}+\frac {7x^2}{54}+K_1e^{3x}+K_2x+K_3}$$

Answer (score 0):

According to undetermined coefficient, the characteristics equation is 
$$r^3-3r^2=0$$
$$r^2(r-3)-0$$
so the roots are
$$x_0=0$$
$$x_1=0$$
$$x_2=3$$
the complementary solution is
$$y_c=c_0+c_1x+c_2e^{3x}$$
the particular solution 
$$y_p=Ax^2+Bx+C\rightarrow Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2$$ 
then you can complete the solution